# Connecting a restaurant website with Microsoft Azure online server database

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm building a website for an online delivery restaurant by using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and I want to connect the website with the **Azure Data Studio**. I'm almost done with the website and I already have the tables ready on Azure. I just wanted to make sure that if it is possible to connect them through node.js or any other way? I also seeking any other recommendation for the best way to connect them because I want to save data in the DB and keep retrieve it whenever the customer wants to see his previous orders.

Please let me know if I'm on the right path and if anyone has done anything similar to this before.

**Updates:**

I will have the following pages:
 - The login screen for the: Owner, Employees in the restaurants, and users.
 - Screen for the user to view food items and to place an order.
 - Screen for the Kitchen to receive the orders and to process it.
 - Screen for the delivery.

All these screens and their functions will be connected to a database where all the data will be saved and the user could view any previous orders for the past 90 days.

**Below are the tables showing in the Azure Data Studio:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the Microsoft Azure online server?" Are you referring to a specific service? What do you have running in Azure now? Are you trying to access something from outside of Azure? Please edit your question to be more specific, and to also include what issue(s) you're running into.

Comment: @ David Makogon: Thank you for your response. I just updated the question and added more info and a pic to make it more clear. Please let me know if this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, first you need to create an Azure web app and need to deploy your existing node.js project on it. In your node.js app you need to create sql connection and use it to insert, update, delete or query the data from database. Follow the below tutorial to connect to database on Azure.

[Create a Node.js web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs)

As I don't know which SQL DB you are using here are tutorial for common 3 DB on Azure:

1) If you are using Azure SQL database then,

[Quickstart: Use Node.js to query an Azure SQL database](http:////learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs)

2) Or if you are using MySQL then refer this,

[Azure Database for MySQL: Use Node.js to connect and query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-nodejs)

3) Or if you are using Azure CosmoDB SQL then refer this,

[Tutorial: Build a Node.js web app using JavaScript SDK to manage Azure Cosmos DB SQL API data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application)

Comment: This is not really true; web apps are just one of many services in Azure to run code. And you're assuming the OP even wants to run their code in Azure: all they said was "I already have the tables ready in Azure" and asking if it's possible to connect to it (implying that maybe the service is running somewhere else). Also, just posting links to tutorials for each database service isn't really an answer (and these are easily findable via the Azure docs site). Based on the OP's writeup, we don't even know what the issue is (the question is unclear and non-specific).

Comment: _put on hold as too broad by charlietfl, Gaurav Mantri, David Makogon, Larry Shatzer, Funk Forty Niner 16 hours ago_
I wish that I could know how do you guys help people who ask questions and in a real need for someone to help? You are putting this question on hold instead of asking me any questions or even trying to help with anything in this matter! If I was one of you, then I swear that I'll do my best to help anyone and to try to understand their questions. Put in mind that most people don't know a lot about programming and they ask to get help not to get rejected and get more depressed

Comment: I AM VERY GLAD THAT I WAS ABLE TO CONNECT MY WEB PAGES TO AZURE DATABASE THROUGH NODE.JS

**WELL DONE**